# Why do I get this error when working with Selenium? And what is the solution?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, xpath, iframe

I want create an account on [ProtonMail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProtonMail).

But when I sign up, I select the user, but I can not send anything to it.

And it gives the following error:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard.
> address page='https://account.protonmail.com/signup?language=en'

```
user=d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
print(user.tag_name)  # Is input
user.send_keys('username')  # Give an error
```

I also used Action Chains, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: please share the link to that page

Comment: thttps://account.protonmail.com/signup?language=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:
2 elements located by `//*[@id="username"]` XPath
The element you want to access is inside iframe.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')))
user=d.find_element_by_xpath('//body[@class="color-norm bg-norm sign-layout-container"]//*[@id="username"]')
user.send_keys('username')
```

Comment: Hey buddy I wanted to thank you but
The power went out
Do you know a good book about web scraping to introduce me ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I never scraped web sites and never learnt about it :)

Comment: I know selenium, working in this field for 6+ years

Comment: Very good
What books and courses did you see ??
Can you tell me too?
I am a novice

Comment: I don't remember, but you can start with tutorials appearing by googling "selenium locators best practices"